# What is the difference between protected and private?

Tags: c++, oop, class, private, protected

I don't understand the difference between protected and private members or methods, as I assumed both will hide the member or the function to access from outside the class.

**What is the difference between the protected and the private keywords?**

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`private` -  only available to be accessed within the class that defines them.

`protected` - accessible in the class that defines them and in other classes which inherit from that class.

Answer (score 16):

Things that are `private` are only visible within the class itself.

Things that are `protected` are visible in the class itself and in subclasses.

Answer (score 9):

The difference is who can access those functions.

- `Private` = only members of the same class can access the function.
- `Protected` = Same as private but derived classes can also access.

Answer (score 6):

Private members can only be used by that classes members and its friends; protected members can be inherited by other classes, and can be used by the classes members and friends.

Answer (score 5):

Private methods are usually visible to class instances (internal implementations), protected methods are visible to subclasses and classes in the same package (inheritance and restricted usage).